# react router and routes is not working , i could not able to navigate to blogs page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

react router and routes is not working , i could not able to navigate to blogs page .
App.js - the following code snippet contains the App.js and the router . i could not use switch due to the latest version of react js .

```
import './App.css';
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import { Navbar,Nav,Container,Row,Col,Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Navigation} from './navbar/navbar.js';
import Luckywheel from './luckywheel/luckywheel';
import Luckymessage from './luckywheel/luckymessage';
import {Routes , Route , BrowserRouter as Routers} from 'react-router-dom'
import Blogs from './tools/blogs';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className='heading'>LUCKY DRAWER</h1>
     
    <Routers> 
    <Navigation /> 
      <Luckywheel />
     <Luckymessage />
    
      <Routes>
        <Route path='blogs'  component={Blogs} />
        <Route path='/' exact component={App} />
   
      </Routes>
     
     
    
     </Routers>
     </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Navbar.js - this file contains the navigation bar code

```
import React ,{Component} from 'react';
import { Navbar,Nav,Container,NavDropdown, } from 'react-bootstrap';


export function Navigation () {
 return(
  
<Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
    <Container>
    
    <Navbar.Brand href='blogs'>Blogs</Navbar.Brand>
    <Navbar.Brand href='/'>Home</Navbar.Brand>
    
    
    </Container>
  </Navbar>    

 )
}

export default Navigation;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` v6 the `Route` component API changed significantly. It no longer takes `component` or `render` or `children` function props, all replaced by a single `element` prop that takes a `ReactElement` (*a.k.a. JSX*).

[Routes and Route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route)

> ```
> declare function Route(
>   props: RouteProps
> ): React.ReactElement | null;
>
> interface RouteProps {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   element?: React.ReactElement | null;
>   index?: boolean;
>   path?: string;
> }
> ```

Swap from `component` to `element` prop and pass the routed component as JSX.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='blogs' element={<Blogs />} />
  <Route path='/' element={<App />} />
</Routes>
```

Answer (score -1):

Install
npm i react-router-dom@5.2.0
To work with switch

Comment: Rather proposing to go back to an older version of the library the question was to help solve it within this library. Moreover the problem is most probably with the Link and not with the Routes (new Switch)